# Google Analytics Goal Destination Regex

Tags: google-analytics, regular-expression

I'm using a destination goal in Google Analytics to capture region specific success pages (like `/en/contact-us/thanks.aspx` and `/de-DE/contact-us/thanks.aspx`), but I would also like to set up a goal that would count all goals regardless of region for URLs that *end with* `/contact-us/thanks.aspx`.
I tried variations of `/(thanks\.aspx)$` with no luck. What is the correct way to format that regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `/contact-us/thanks.aspx` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it is not registering any conversions. when I include the language param, it does.

Comment: Works as is. Not sure why I wasn't seeing it initially.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Regex matching type selected, and enter as the destination:

```
^.*/contact-us/thanks\.aspx$
```

You can use real times conversions to check if it's working.